# Strange results when converting from byte array to string

Tags: c#, character-encoding, ascii

I get strange results when converting byte array to string and then converting the string back to byte array.

Try this:

```
     byte[] b = new byte[1];
    b[0] = 172;
    string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b);

    byte[] b2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
    MessageBox.Show(b2[0].ToString());
```

And the result for me is not 172 as I'd expect but... 63.

Why does it happen?

Comment: 172 is not a defined ASCII char. what you get is `? (63)`

Comment: Obviously your example is a contrived case. What is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 6):

> Why does it happen?

Because ASCII only contains values up to 127.

When faced with binary data which is invalid for the given encoding, `Encoding.GetString` can provide a replacement character, or throw an exception. Here, it's using a replacement character of `?`.

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to achieve, but:

- If you're converting arbitrary binary data to text, use [`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx) instead; do *not* try to use an encoding, as you're not really representing text. You can use [`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) to then decode.
- `Encoding.ASCII` is usually a bad choice, and certainly binary data including a byte of 172 is *not* ASCII text
- You need to work out which encoding you're *actually* using. Personally I dislike using `Encoding.Default` unless you *really* know the data is in the default encoding for the platform you're working on. If you get the choice, using UTF-8 is a good one.

Answer (score 3):

ASCII encoding is a 7-bit encoding. If you take a look into generated string it contains "?" - unrecognized character. You might choose Encoding.Default instead.

Comment: If the OP is trying to encode arbitrary binary data and then decode it again, he shouldn't be using Encoding at all. Suggesting Encoding.Default is a bad idea, IMO.

Comment: I agree. Also, using string to contain binary data is a bad idea.

Comment: Well trying to encode it *like that* is a bad idea. Using base64 is inefficient, but if you only have a text-shaped pipe and you want to transport binary data, that will at least get it there safely...

Answer (score 1):

ASCII is a seven bit character encoding, so 172 falls out of that range, so when converting to a string, it converts to "?" which is used for characters that cannot be represented.